# Apache2 Override default Options directive

Tags: apache2

While configuring Apache2 i've got stuck with this problem:

```
00_default_vhost.conf includes default_vhost.conf
```

**default_vhost.conf**

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts">
        AllowOverride None
        Options Indexes, FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and after that another **vhost.conf** where defined

**vhost.conf**

```
 <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/vhost">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

But last include Options directive seems not working at all. Why? Is there a way to let vhost Options override default?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that TBH... The double `vhost` in the last code is intentional I guess? Oh, and it's slightly offtopic here, you might move it to SUperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: I'm trying to use defaults for most of out sites in 00_default_vhost.conf and trying to define additional Option directive for one of them in vhost.conf. But it doesn't work. Any guesses how to make it work? Or it won't?

Comment: Again: I don't see anything wrong with the config you posted. YOu may want to post the full config or soem details whaat you tested and what results you got. Adn, again: It's offtopic here.